# Prevent expanding horizontally or vertically in fabric line object

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I have below custom line, called edge, with label, how do I prevent controls for horizontal or vertical movement. I see controls, which can allow user to modify line into rectangle.

```
var lr = new Edge([ 250, 125, 250, 175 ], {
    fill: 'green',
    stroke: 'green',
    strokeWidth: 1,
    selectable: true,
    evented: true,
    hasBorders:false,
    cornerStyle:'circle',
    centeredScaling: false,
    lockScalingY:false,
    label: '1'
  });
```

#### Example -

[image]

### Problem, line now become rectangle.

I tried below to set to true, which makes the line to have only one length. How to make this fabric line object, such that user will not expand the line to rectangle?

```
lockScalingX: false,
lockScalingY:false,
```

[image]

#### Code sample

https://codepen.io/ajayramesh/pen/NWNpaRW

Answer (score 0):

Using custom control object, now I am able to control each control objects.
doc - http://fabricjs.com/controls-api

```
    // tl, mt, tr, mr, br, mb, bl, ml and mtr.
    //lr.setControlVisible("tl", false)
    lr.setControlVisible("mt", false)
    lr.setControlVisible("tr", false)
    lr.setControlVisible("mr", false)
    // lr.setControlVisible("br", false)
    lr.setControlVisible("mb", false)
    lr.setControlVisible("bl", false)
    lr.setControlVisible("ml", false)
    //lr.setControlVisible("mtr", false)
    return lr;
```